Parent process cannot Read what child process output by printf at each time the child process do that
Parent process should Reads what child process output by printf at each time the child process do that, as like when I invoke hello_world.exe in a console of Windows, the source code of which is shown below, where the exe prints out 8 lines of text at each second.
But, the parent process can Read only accumulated what the child process has output, when the child terminated.
// hello_world.cpp
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 8;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
    {
        printf("[%d/%d] Hello, world!\n", k, n);
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}

// parent.cpp
//
int main(void)
{
    char* pcmd = (char*)"<path to>/hello_world";

    HANDLE hpipe_read;
    HANDLE hpipe_write;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    CreatePipe(&hpipe_read, &hpipe_write, &sa, 0);

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdOutput = hpipe_write;
    si.hStdError = hpipe_write;

    CreateProcess(NULL, pcmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    HANDLE childProcess = pi.hProcess;
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    char buff[1024];
    DWORD lenPeek = 0;
    DWORD lenRead = 0;
    bool bloop = true;
    while (bloop)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject(childProcess, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            bloop = false;
        }
        PeekNamedPipe(hpipe_read, NULL, 0, NULL, &lenPeek, NULL);
        if (lenPeek)
        {
            ReadFile(hpipe_read, buff, sizeof(buff), &lenRead, NULL);
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(hpipe_write);
    CloseHandle(hpipe_read);

    buff[lenRead] = '\0';
    printf(buff);
    return 0;
}


